# Firefox 59.0.1 crashes at start on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, firefox

My firefox crashes at start every time I try to launch it. I tried to launch it:

- graphically (by clicking the icon)
- with a terminal: `$ firefox`

None of this worked.
When launching from the terminal, I get the following error:

```
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 5820
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
Bus error (core dumped)
```

I rebooted my computer, I uninstalled firefox and reinstalled it, but none of this worked neither.

**Ubuntu:** `Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS 64-bit`
**Firefox:** `Mozilla Firefox 59.0.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exacts same problem with FF 59.0.2.

I tried unsuccessfully to start FF in safe mode.

I resolved it by removing a "lock" file inside the default profile (~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxx.default/lock)

Answer (score 0):

Today (1 week later), a patch has been released. I did

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It installed the version `Mozilla Firefox 59.0.2`, and it works perfectly now.

Comment: I had the exacts same problem with FF 59.0.2. As I didn't have any update, I tried unsuccessfully to start FF in safe mode. In my case, I resolved it removing a "lock" file inside the default profile (~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxx.default/lock)

Comment: @marianobianchi Interesting.. It means you are certainly closer to the solution than I was. You should post your own answer on this.